# Can helicopter or aircraft intro flight hours count towards a private pilot license?

Tags: general-aviation, logging

I'm trying to figure out whether I'd prefer to fly helicopters or fixed-wing aircraft and am taking a few intro flights where the other person lets me fly for a little bit.

Can these hours count towards my helicopter / aircraft private pilot certificate? If yes, do I need a logbook or what kind of proof do I need?

Comment: Which country or regulations are you asking about?

Comment: Get your fixed wing PPL first, you don't want to be paying $300+/hour to learn how to use the radios and airspace, once you get your PPL in fixed wing, the transition time is shorter for helicopters.

Comment: Ron, I'm not very well-versed with how licensing works. In the aircraft world, do people get a private pilot's license with an endorsement for only fixed-wing, and then you can get an endorsement for rotorcraft with additional training (it's actually the same license, just different endorsements)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these hours can be counted towards PPL, if you fly with a flight instructor next to you, which is generally the case if you go to a flight school and ask for "introductory flights" anyway.

In my case, they provided me with a tiny logbook for free so I can log my hours.

Comment: And if you give them a copy of a birth cert or passport so they can make a TSA endorsement.

Comment: Might be worth saying though that while these introductory flights technically count towards the required hours, they do very little in the form of teaching and really aren't that beneficial in gaining your certificate. Most pilots take significantly longer to get the license than the bare minimums, so I wouldn't worry about getting these hours recorded, usually the log book entry is more of a sentimental thing (hey, I started here).